# Xcode 5 app nor working under released version of IOS 8

Tags: xcode5, xcode6

The iPad/iPhone app which runs perfectly under IOS 7 and prior versions but fails under IOS 8.

I do not have xcode 6 installed so I do not have the IOS 8 simulators.

The error comes when downloading data files.  Gets 80% through then errors out. Don't know what is causing the error, could even be a time-out issue.  I have no idea.

I reported the "bug" to Apple and have a ticket open but no action on it yet.

My questions is what to do next?

Should I install xcode 6 even though there appears to be quite a few problems with it?

Is it possible to download just the IOS 8 simulators into xcode 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the mystery you need to install Xcode 6 so you can see where exactly the problem occurs. Without it you're left with a crashing app I'm afraid.

Xcode 6 will be necessary to submit new versions of your app sooner or later anyway. The good news is that you can install both versions of Xcode on the same machine: either upgrade your current Xcode 5 installation via the App Store, or download Xocde 6 separately from the Apple Dev Center. If you're upgrading to Xcode 6 you can download Xocde 5 from the Apple Dev Center (there's an option called "older versions of Xcode").

Good luck!

Comment: The update went smoothly.  Just beginning to triage the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is literally nothing to go on here.
Yes, you should install Xcode 6 and iOS 8, reproduce the problem, and triage it.

It is not possible to use the iOS 8 simulator in Xcode 5.

What are the "quite a few problems" that you fear in Xcode 6?